# how do I remove space between the number and the filesize?

Tags: linux, bash

```
21.8G   65.3 G   /user/x
3.5G    12.7 G   /user/y
1.4G    4.3 G    /user/z
1.3G    3.9 G    /user/s
746.4M  2.2 G    /user/t
```

I want it to look like

```
746.4M  2.2G    /user/x
582.3M  1.7G    /user/y
523.4K  1.5M    /user/z
494      1.4K    /user/s
449.2M  5.7G    /user/t
```

Comment: Which program is it that produces the output? How are you going to get the expected output from that input? The sizes aren't even the same.

Comment: Have you tried `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I tried, was able to do it for first column, how do I do it for the second column?

Comment: How did you solve it for first column?

Comment: hdfs dfs -du -h /user | sed 's/ //' | sort -hr |head -n 5. This helped me remove the space for the first column, I want it for the second column as well.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum control, provide your own format string.

```
while read -r used free dir; do
  printf '%-7s %-7s %s\n' "$used" "$free" "$dir"
done
```

...in that case, adding 7 extra spaces of padding; adjust as you choose. (`%-7s` means a 7-space field, with the text on the left; `%7s` would be a 7-space field with the text on the right)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "21.8 G   65.3 G   /user/x
3.5 G    12.7 G   /user/y
1.4 G    4.3 G    /user/z
1.3 G    3.9 G    /user/s
746.4 M  2.2 G    /user/t" | sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\2/g'
```

removes all single spaces between a digit and a letter. But this could also change the path. `g` stands for global.

```
$ echo "21.8G   65.3 G   /user/x
3.5G    12.7 G   /user/y
1.4G    4.3 G    /user/z
1.3G    3.9 G    /user/s
746.4M  2.2 G    /user/t" | sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\2/'
```

removes only the first match in each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input
21.8G   65.3 G   /user/x
3.5G    12.7 G   /user/y
1.4G    4.3 G    /user/z
1.3G    3.9 G    /user/s
746.4M  2.2 G    /user/t
$ awk '{print $1, $2 $3, $4}' OFS=\\t input
21.8G   65.3G   /user/x
3.5G    12.7G   /user/y
1.4G    4.3G    /user/z
1.3G    3.9G    /user/s
746.4M  2.2G    /user/t
```

or perhaps:

```
$ awk '{printf "%6s  %6s  %s\n", $1, $2 $3, $4}'  input
 21.8G   65.3G  /user/x
  3.5G   12.7G  /user/y
  1.4G    4.3G  /user/z
  1.3G    3.9G  /user/s
746.4M    2.2G  /user/t
```